# how to create a 30% off promotion with flat shipping and exclude one category

Tags: flat, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to create a promotion that gives flat shipping rate and and 30% discount as well but I want to exclude one sale category from it.

I made one myself for the discount but whenever I add anything from the sale category the code doesn't work (sale category has free shipping to it)

Comment: Is it you want 
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    Shipping Method  is  [flatrate] 
    If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
        Category  is not  7